# pass a whole string as argument between python and bash

Tags: python, bash, arguments

```
cat /tmp/testme
#!/usr/bin/env  python3
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
print(sys.argv[1])
```

It is simple ,just to print argument passed from bash to python.

```
x="i am a book"
/tmp/testme "i am a book"
/tmp/testme
i am a book
```

The string `i am a book` can passed into python program as a whole string.

```
/tmp/testme  ${x}
/tmp/testme
i
echo ${x}
i am a book
```

Why python can't deal with ${x} `i am a book` as a whole,it get only the first character in the string as argument.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you please elaborate a little and tell us your goal and what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: Put the argument in quotes: `/tmp/testme  "${x}"`

Comment: Without double-quotes around it, the shell will try to split the variable's value into words and also expand anything that looks like a wildcard into a list of matching filenames. You generally don't want either of these (and if you do, you probably want it in a different form), so you should almost always put double-quotes around variable references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the line `/tmp/testme  ${x}`, bash will expand the contents of `x`, and will ultimately execute `/tmp/testme i am a book`. Therefore, `sys.argv` will become `['/tmp/testme', 'i', 'am', 'a', 'book']`.

To achieve the desired behaviour, `${x}` should be quoted, like `"${x}"`. Then bash will execute `/tmp/testme 'i am a book'`.

Here is an example with a bash script. With `set -x`, bash will print commands and their arguments as they are executed, after all variables have been evaluated.

```
$ cat testme
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys.argv)

$ cat exampleBashScript.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

x="i am a book"
./testme ${x}
./testme "${x}"

$ ./exampleBashScript.sh 
+ x='i am a book'
+ ./testme i am a book
['./testme', 'i', 'am', 'a', 'book']
+ ./testme 'i am a book'
['./testme', 'i am a book']
```